# Successfully updating value of data attribute but not refreshing

Tags: javascript, jquery, attributes, attr, updating

From what I've read, `jquery.attr()` is what I need to update the data-attributes of this div.  The div contains an audioplayer on the page and the ultimate goal is to update the data-thumb, data-source, data-bgimage, etc. for a div called "ap1"--for now, let's just target successfully updating data-source which contains the location of the mp3 we want to switch to (string).

I am using the following code that is successfully updating the value (per the alert replying 'sounds/song_to_change_to.mp3') however the corresponding player is not being fully updated--only the text-based components are updating in the view but a 'refresh' isn't occurring for the data attributes:

```
$('#ap1').attr("data-source", r_cont);
alert($('#ap1').attr("data-source"));
```

`r_cont` contains a simple string such as 'sounds/song_to_change_to.mp3'.

When the alert runs it shows the name of the new mp3 but the player does not update.  Note here that text components are updating in the html (such as `$("#activeartist").text(title);`) and the changes are viewable immediately. The code I am using initiates the player using the following:

```
    jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {

    var settings_ap = {
        disable_volume: 'off'
    };
    dzsap_init('#ap1',settings_ap);
});
```

I have inserted this into a function which runs when a link is clicked to update the current song playing.  The same identical function is used in a script tag right before the `</body>` to initialize the player with a default song on page load.

This is the div in my html code that presents the original player (with a default song).

```
<section class="dzsap-sticktobottom">
<div id="ap1" class="audioplayer-tobe" style="width:100%; margin-top:10px; margin-bottom: 10px;" **data-thumb**="img/thumb2.jpg" **data-bgimage**="img/bg.jpg" **data-source**="sounds/itsabeautifulday.mp3">
    <div class="meta-artist"><span id="activeartist" class="the-artist">Artist Name</span><span id="activesong" class="the-name"><a href="#" target="_blank">Song Name</a></span>
    </div>
</div>
</section>
```

When the function runs, the goal is to update the player with the selected song and associated bg image, thumbnail, etc.  The function takes as input 6 strings and passes them along but let's for now just pretend it will take as input 1 string which contains the mp3 path.

Note: I'm wondering if ap1 needs to be torn down and reinitialized each time.  I tried to use `$('#ap1').remove()` in the function to tear down the existing div each time a link was clicked and then append the entire div with `$("#ap1").html('HTML_AP1_CODE_HERE>')` but it only came through as unformatted text.

Comment: Use **$.data()** instead of $.attr()... check out: _http://api.jquery.com/jquery.data/_

Comment: should be working through API of `dzsap_init`. If it doesn't support what you want, find another plugin that does

Comment: I have been told that data only updates the internally stored variable and will not do what i need to actually refresh the page.  Is that not true?

Comment: @charlietfl, can you provide a bit more detail by chance.  I was under the impression that dzsap_init was internal to this code I got for the player and not a shared library.  A quick search indicates this is true as it only yields results related to ZoomSounds player (which I was I am using).

Comment: I have no idea where `dzsap_init` comes from or where API docs are. Worst case you could clone the element, before intiializing `dzsap_init` , then replace it and reintiialize

Comment: @charlietfl Could you provide a quick sample on how to tackle that?  I am still relatively new to jquery.  Thanks in advance.